# Recursive Method Giving Me an Error Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a recursive method in Java. It is used to generate prefixes based on a string of digits entered by the user. This is a homework assignment. I'm not asking how to do this program/method. However, I am asking for help in pointing out what is causing me to have the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
>       at Words.listCompletions(Words.java:81)
>       at Words.listCompletions(Words.java:86)
>       at Words.listCompletions(Words.java:86)
>       at Words.(Words.java:18)
>       at MindRead.main(MindRead.java:17)

Sometimes when I encounter errors in my programs I can't see whats causing the error to occur even if it is right in front of my face because after awhile I start to panic. Any help would be appreciated!I thank you for taking the time to view my method.

This is my recursive method:

```
public void listCompletions(String prefix,String digits){
    if(digits.length()==0)
        p.println(prefix);
    String s=keypad(digits.charAt(0));
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        char ch=s.charAt(i);
        prefix=prefix+ch;
        digits=digits.substring(1);
        listCompletions(prefix,digits);
    }
}//end of listCompletions
```

This is the keypad function that it calls on line 4:

```
public String keypad(char n){
    String letters=null;
    switch(n){
        case '0':
            letters="";
            break;
        case '1':
            letters="";
            break;
        case '2':
            letters="abc";
            break;
        case '3':
            letters="def";
            break;
        case '4':
            letters="ghi";
            break;
        case '5':
            letters="jkl";
            break;
        case '6':
            letters="mno";
            break;
        case '7':
            letters="pqrs";
            break;
        case '8':
            letters="tuv";
            break;
        case '9':
            letters="wxyz";
            break;
        default:
            System.err.println();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("\n\nERROR: "+n+" is "+
                " not a valid entry.\n       Valid entries are "+
                "numbers 0 through 9.\n\n");
    }//switch END
    return letters;
}//end of keypad
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We need to see your code in order to tell you what's wrong. Please include it in the question.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to read the first character of an empty string... your code may miss a test for empty string...
Or now that there is the code : a return statement or an else...

Answer (score 2):

Your error is there :

```
if(digits.length()==0)
    p.println(prefix);
String s=keypad(digits.charAt(0));
```

Without a return statement in the if or an else to wrap the following the last line will be executed even with an empty string, resulting in this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The index that's causing this exception is index 0 - the first character of the string. So you are dealing with an empty ("") string

In your recursive method, you are not checking for an empty string. At/near the top of your method, you should have a base case like

```
if (str == null || str.length == 0) {
  ... // handle null / empty string specially
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I appreciate the help! Its stuff like this that I overlook when I stress out about errors.